# DataBase dropped automatically in PHPmyAdmin & Mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, symfony4

I have a problem with my Mysql database, I develop an aplication on symfony 4 and when I create my database that it is via PhpMyadmin or via the symfony console, my database is automatically removed within 24 hours follow and I lose all my data, can you help me on this point?

thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question sounds like guessing plus a bit of magic. Although people are quite good at guessing here, there are no wizzards. You must provide debug information, from logs, from application outputs, the beginning of your SQL dump, your server environment, .... for us beeing able to give you an adequate answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the logs of object dropping. You can do it by doing this :

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';    

select event_time,user_host,argument
from mysql.general_log
where command_type='Query' and 
upper(argument) rlike '(DROP|DELETE|TRUNCATE)+';
```

Read this post to enable the logs in MySQL and see when and why your database is dropped:
[How to find MYSQL Logs for Drop Delete Record?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212281/how-to-find-mysql-logs-for-drop-delete-record/212291)